# LinkedIn OAuth uid changed?

Tags: oauth, omniauth, linkedin-api

We've been using OmniAuth to facilitate "login with your LinkedIn credentials" (and other OAuth2 providers as well).

Today 3 of us tried exercising the flow and discovered that the OAuth2 callback from LinkedIn contained a *different* `id` field than it had on our many previous login attempts.  As a result our app doesn't recognize us as being the same user, since the SSO provider's `id` changed.

The [LinkedIn API docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile) say the `id` field is "A unique identifying value for the member.
This value is linked to your specific application.  Any attempts to use it with a different application will result in a "404 - Invalid member id" error."  As far as we can tell we haven't changed our client key/client secret or anything like that.  We did change DNS on the app recently but I assume that LinkedIn (and other OAuth2 SSO providers) identify the app based on the client key and secret, not the reverse DNS lookup or IP address or anything like that.

Is this normal?  Do `uid`s provided in OAuth2 callbacks "expire" and receive a new value the next time authentication happens, and if so, how can we identify it as being the same user?  What are we missing?

Comment: We just ran into the same problem possibly after migrating from linkedin profile v1 to v2 (since v1 will be deprectated) and this is quite breaking =_=